Privacy-focused, offline, non-ads, customizable, dictionary Android app
I am having a hard time finding a satisfactory Android app for a dictionary. Maybe you can help me. I have the following criteria:

It either must have publicly available source code (I don't say "open source" because there can be a license that allows you to see the code, but which still doesn't meet the criteria of being an open source license) OR its permissions must be so strict, that it would be unable to see any files outside its own app folder. Not even files in, say, "download" directory.

It either must be zero-priced and free from ads, OR it must give its user the ability to remove all ads and get all functions with permanent purchases.

A user must have the ability to add a custom third-party dictionary. And either one of the supported formats is Stardict dictionaries OR Stardict dictionaries must be able to get converted into at the least one of the supported formats (i.e. either there are tools available for such conversion somewhere, OR it can be done manually without requiring too much work)

It must support the playback of audio files for dictionary entries. So I would be able to hear how words are pronounced.

It must be compatible with Android 12 (i.e. must be able to work under Android 12)

It must be able to work completely offline

It must not require me to run a web server on my own smartphone or computer in order to use the app on my smartphone (looking at you, Silverdict!)

If the app has publicly UNavailable source code, then the app must be available for downloading at Google Play Store.


